# Bootstrap 3 gallery auto slide activating after modal opens?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and I have a gallery on the home page and a modal. I have disabled the auto slide on the gallery by using:

```
function galleryCarousel() {
        $ub('.carousel').carousel({
        pause: true,
        interval: false       
    })
};
```

My only issue is when someone clicks on the button to bring up the modal, the gallery suddenly starts to auto slide again and will continue until you close the modal. The strange thing this only happens after you click to go to the second image in the gallery will it start auto slide again.

I've tried several ways to fix this to no avail.

You can see the prototype working here: http://copy-writer-otter-74032.netlify.com/

Simply advance the gallery to the next slide, then click on "profile" button at the bottom of the page to bring up the modal - wait a few seconds and watch the gallery start auto sliding again.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are already initializing your slider with the data attributes. This means the default slider is applied. The reason it seems to be not on auto, is because the slider won't move when you hover over it by default. As soon as you open the modal, the slider does not receive a hover, and it will start to move. Just place your mouse on the header, or open one of the dropdowns, and you'll see it starts moving.

The easy solution would be to add `data-interval="false"` to your slider element. This also means you can remove that javascript.

Have a look at the demo I created.
Whithout the data attribute: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVRaeR
With the data attribute: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdzoKj